# incluir metadados em PDF

Tags: delphi

Estou precisando incluir um texto na área de metadados de um pdf impresso via delphi utilizando o PDFCreator version 3.51 como impressora virtual.

Pesquisei Tentei fazer pelo manual do PDFCreator e pesquisei na internet mas não consegui fazer. Alguém poderia ajudar?

*Abaixo a parte do código para a impressão:*

```
uses ... ActiveX, ComObj, PDFCreator_COM_TLB;

//Parte da procedure que faz a impressão:
var
   sDocUser:         String;
   bTemPdf:          Boolean;
   job,
   PDFObject:        OleVariant;
   pdf:                    IPDFCreator;
   LPrintJob:         IPrintJob;
   LQueue:            IQueue;

begin
     ...
     sDocUser := skey + '-' + sDoc + '-' + '7899067733';
     SetDefautPrinter('PDFCreator');
     rptIProt.PrepareReport;  // relatório feito em fastreport
     PDFObject := CoPdfCreatorObj.Create;
     LQueue := CoQueue.Create;
     LQueue.Initialize;
     LPrintJob.SetProfileSetting('Keyword', sDocUser);  // linha com o erro
```

error apresentado:

> project pReport.exe raised Exception class EAccessViolation with
>   message 'Access violation at address 0054EB4A in module' pReport.exe
>   '. Read of address 00000000 '. Process pReport.exe (9408)

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e insira mais informações, assim podemos te ajudar melhor. Coloque o código do que tentou até agora, vai que faltou você apenas preencher uma propriedade? :D

Comment: Coloque um [mcve] do código que está em questão.

Comment: Ninguém teria como ajudar???